# Using git submodules through ssh with buildbot

Tags: git, ssh, git-submodules, buildbot

I have a git repository with submodules that are linked with different external git-servers. How can I pass ssh authentification for each submodule and user? Can I put separate options for each submodule in Buildbot?

Can I checkout every submodule on the neccessary branch automatically? And can I view not only root changelog, but every submodule's changelog in one time?

Comment: Probably you should ask in buildbot mailing list which is the official support channel they have. Then, if you gen an answer, paste it here